# Command not found ./configure | DDosim

Tags: linux, backtrack

I am trying to run the command to configure DDosim https://sourceforge.net/projects/ddosim/. I have installed Libnet0 and Libnet0-Dev . But when i try to enter command like

```
root@bt:~/ddosim# sudo ./configure
```

It simply says Command Not Found. 
Any idea what could be the issue ?

Comment: could you please post the output of `ls` command....(list of files in the directory);

Comment: Thank you for commenting . It was permission issue . chmod a+x did the job .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file exists, is the executable bit set on the file? That's the likely issue, because if it's not seArchable+eXecutable, it won't work. Also check ownership.
Try "chmod a+x ./configure"
Then run it again "./configure"
It should work now. I'v run into this many times before if the permissions were set wrong on the configure script of a program's source code.